# How to supply securely username and password to SFTP Host in a Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, cron, sftp

As I am running this script as a Cron Job, I need to enter username and password every time when I try to SFTP to host. Below is the sample script I made which demands some modifications

```
#!/bin/sh

sftp -i /path/to/private/key/ username@123.123.123.123 <<EOF
put /home/sample.txt /home/
exit
EOF
```

Instead of private key path, I believe we insert password path. Although this is human intervention. I need it to be automated.

How can I resolve the issue ?

Comment: What's the problem with the private key approach?

Comment: @Leon: There is nothing wrong in it. I can use it. But the main question lies here is, how do I automate as I am using cron Job ?

Comment: If you can use a private key, just use the script you have. What do you want to "automate" about that? It's automatic already!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: That's correct. If I am using a password based authentication for sftp then what would be the possible syntax, will it be like sftp -p /path/to/password/ username@123.123.123.123 ?